# Customizing the bottom toolbar in emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

How do I customize the bottom toolbar in emacs? I want it similar to the toolbar in Whateveryouwant theme.

[image: The Whatever you want theme]

Answer (score 2):

This toolbar is called the mode-line in emacs terminology. You can customize the modeline using the variable `mode-line-format` which is a list that you can insert modeline variables into. You can find some pretty good tutorials and documentation on what modeline variables to use [here](http://www.hollenback.net/index.php/EmacsModeLine) and [here](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Mode-Line-Top.html).

It should be possible to reproduce your desired toolbar using the `mode-line-format`. You can always have a look into the color-theme-library.el to see how your color theme is customized.

For example to have your mode-line print a greeting :

```
(setq-default mode-line-format
  (list " "
        "Hello Mode-Line!"
        " "
        )
)
```